# How to make join query for mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables, one (lets call it 'tracks') will have music track information like title, time, sample file, price and all stuff needed. The second table (lets call it 'categories') would have id of track from first table, type of category (instrument, genre, mood and so on) and category id.

There can be unknown number of categories for specific track. For example, the track with id=1 could have instrument categories 3 and 4, mood categories 1, 2, 3 and so on.

I need to get the sortable (by title, time, price or whatever) list of tracks that also uses LIMIT (for pagination) filtered by mood or instrument or whatever type(s).

Can anyone help me to assemble query like that? I have no clue how to begin.

Here is example of table structure:

Table 'tracks'

```
+----+---------+-------+------+
| id |  title  | Price | Time |
+----+---------+-------+------+
|  1 | Title 1 |    10 |    0 |
|  2 | Title 2 |     9 |    1 |
|  3 | Title 3 |     8 |    2 |
+----+---------+-------+------+
```

Table 'categories'

```
    +----+------------+-------------+----------+
    | id |    type    | category_id | track_id |
    +----+------------+-------------+----------+
    |  1 | instrument |           1 |        1 |
    |  2 | instrument |          10 |        1 |
    |  3 | genre      |           1 |        1 |
    |  4 | mood       |          15 |        2 |
    +----+------------+-------------+----------+
```

I would of course use int as category type but i use words as an example.

**UPDATE on fatal flaw:**

juergen d solution works well but it has one fatal flaw. If i have all possible instruments, genres and moods in a seperate dropdown and i want to filter out a track that has instrument 1, mood 2 and genre 3 by selecting dropdown boxes. The list shows all tracks that has instrument 1 OR mood 2 OR... not AND.

Can anybody help me modify it?

Comment: You need a bigger design

Comment: You're design is flawed, and I hope someone will give you the correct desired design.

Comment: @user1365447 I think you should make more of an effort at coming up with the correct desired design yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better DB design would be

Table 'tracks'

```
+----+---------+-------+------+
| id |  title  | Price | Time |
+----+---------+-------+------+
|  1 | Title 1 |    10 |    0 |
|  2 | Title 2 |     9 |    1 |
|  3 | Title 3 |     8 |    2 |
+----+---------+-------+------+
```

Table 'categories'

```
+----+------------+
| id |    type    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | instrument |
|  2 | genre      |
|  3 | mood       |
+----+------------+
```

Table 'track_categories'

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
| category_id | sub_category | track_id | 
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           1 |           3  |        1 |
|           1 |           1  |        1 |
|           3 |           1  |        1 |
|           2 |           3  |        2 |
+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Then you can run the query (for instance for genre tracks)

```
select t.*
from tracks t
join track_categories tc on tc.track_id = t.id
join categories c on c.id = tc.category_id
where c.type = 'genre'
```

And if you want to select tracks having a specifik combination of types then use

```
select t.title
from tracks t
join track_categories tc on tc.track_id = t.id
join categories c on c.id = tc.category_id
group by t.title
having sum(c.type = 'instrument' and tc.sub_category = 1) > 0
and sum(c.type = 'mood' and tc.sub_category = 2) > 0
and sum(c.type = 'genre' and tc.sub_category = 3) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use that! How about a query?

Comment: I disagree. A better design would have a table for genres, a table for moods, and a table for instruments

Comment: Because "For example, the track with id=1 could have instrument categories 3 and 4, mood categories 1, 2, 3 and so on."

Comment: How the query would look like then?

Comment: @Strawberry: Oh, I missed that. I updated my answer but did only add another column to the `track_categories` table.

Comment: The solution has fatal flaw, more info on original post under edit.

Comment: @user1365447: That is not a fatal flaw - that is just a different requirement with a different query.